# since its foundation and beginning broadcasting

Tags: gerunds

*TV Nova is the commercial television station that has been since its foundation and beginning broadcasting in 1994 a key media player in the television market in our republic.*

Do you find this sentence correct? I have the problems with "beginning broadcasting". Is it possible to have two gerunds next to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an awkward sentence which remains awkward even when made clearer by repositioning a phrase:

> Since its foundation and beginning broadcasting in 1994, TV Nova is
>   the commercial television station that has been a key media player in
>   the television market in our republic.

We should move more info into the initial **Since**-clause:

> Since its foundation and beginning broadcasting as a commercial television station in 1994, TV Nova has been a key media player in the television market in our republic.

Those changes make for a clear main clause:

> TV Nova has been a key media player in the television market in our
>   republic.

Further improvements:

"since its foundation and beginning broadcasting".

> Since beginning broadcasting in 1994, the year of its founding as a commercial television station, TV Nova has been a key media player in the television market in our republic.

Answer (score 0):

TV Nova is the commercial television station that has been **since its foundation and beginning broadcasting in 1994** a key media player in the television market in our republic.

The sentence is not grammatical. "Since" has to be followed by two clauses with the same structure, or two nouns. But not a mix of the two. Not one verb and one noun.

TV Nova is the commercial television station that has been - **since it was founded and began broadcasting in 1994** - a key media player in the television market in our country.

English likes parallelism in structure. By using two action verbs: found and began, the awkwardness is avoided. However, **sticklers will say there is still no absolute parallelism since there is one active and one passive verb**.

Kindly note that here: broadcasting is a direct object in the form of a gerund.

Another way to say this is:

**The commercial television station TV NOVA has been a key media player in our country's television market since it began broadcasting in 1994**.

I don't see that the founding adds anything, quite frankly because you can't broadcast unless the organization is founded.

There are other forms this sentence can take. These are  just two ways it can written.